# Firebase Cloud Firestore throws "client is offline"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

About 3 out of 4 times loading the page I get this error from the firestore client SDK (web). This slows development down tremendously. Auth, Realtime DB and Storage work perfectly fine.

```
Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

[image: Error]

Is there something I can do about this?

Comment: You can also get this error if you're using a Firestore emulator and it's not running.

Comment: Thanks, @Ninjakannon, That was the issue for me. I initialized the firebase on the emulator and had forgotten about it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's currently an interaction between the clients and routing on the backend that results in this problem. As a result the client believes the network is failing and goes offline.

We'll be rolling out a fix for this soon. Exact times I can't promise but this is among our top priority issues to fix.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: We've rolled out a fix. If you see this again please let us know.

Comment: More troubleshooting steps would be useful.  I'm seeing the problem, but it's not clear what sorts of reports you want other than the obvious "FireStore isn't working."

Comment: At the time this was reported it was a known issue. You can enable verbose client-side logging with Firestore.setLogLevel('debug'). Something may jump out at you like QUOTA_EXCEEDED messages, but if you really are seeing 400 errors from the server from the javascript SDK, it's likely a bug and best reported here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Still having "client is offline" issue after reconnecting to the Internet mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188476/firestore-fails-to-retrieve-data-after-reconnecting-to-the-internet Using Android SDK (firestore version: 17.1.3). Do you have any update on this?

Comment: Note that comments on a year-old question that's already been answered are unlikely to get answered quickly. This issue was reported immediately at launch (regarding the web SDK) and was resolved. The android SDK being slow to recover after coming back online is a separate issue. See our CHANGELOG: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-firestore/CHANGELOG.md -- there have been recent changes on this front. 17.1.5 included a change that made switching between networks better. The forthcoming 18.0.1 should address resuming from airplane mode.

Comment: I'm seeing the problem the latest version of Firestore (19.0.0).

Comment: I'm still having this buggy error ,I'm using latest version of now firebase-firestore:21.1.1 for android .Will you fix this problem for good.

Comment: Still seeing the problem with version 21.3.0 of firestore.

Comment: I'm having the same issue still. I have used firebase and firestore with Xamarin.iOS. in that i'm facing this same issue a lot

Comment: As I've said before, this issue was filed a few days after we launched the service, years ago now. There was a specific problem then that has been fixed. If you're still having issues, you should either [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support) or [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Me too comments here aren't going to get you any help. Please either [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support) or [file and issue on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/new/choose).

Comment: I am getting the same issue, I have reported to firebase support as well as posted an issue here https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/752

Comment: I reported an issue for Realtime database and they are about to resolve it here -> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2385

Comment: this isn't a relevant answer any longer, would it be possible to update it with more detail about what causes this issue? I have this happen to about 0.1-0.5% of my users which is frequent enough that it's causing problems (especially cause it can't be replicated locally)

Answer (score 10):

I updated all my packages and I ran into this issue.
I enabled offline persistence for my web app and that fixed the problem:

```
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: This only helps if the client already had a successful connection with data from a prior request.  Otherwise, there's nothing in the cache, and while there's no error thrown, the client also wouldn't have the content which was supposed to be derived from the data.

Answer (score 7):

For me, the same error happened when

1. project_id is wrong
2. port for emulator is 8081 instead of 8080. (when port was 8081 the emulator was working well, with UI opened normally and so on but the error kept showing. I fixed the problem by changing the port back to 8080)

The error message is very misleading.

Answer (score 3):

I have just spent about 3 hours trying to fix it. There was something wrong with my emulator. I had to remove it, then created new and now it is working. So if you face this issue, give it try.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might occur because you're integrating firebase 'web' SDK in your React Native (RN CLI not Expo) app. So in order to use firebase in your react native app you must follow this tutorial: https://rnfirebase.io/

It must work.

Answer (score 1):

For me, just restarting the emulator fixed it.

Comment: Same code works for iOS. I can't believe I wasted whole night for trouble shooting, updating packages, update dependencies at gradle..... until I saw this comment. Thanks you!!

Answer (score 1):

In my app as well this error occurs at the first run after installation. I was able to get rid of above bug by refreshing/restarting the Activity.

```
if (e.getMessage().equals("Failed to get document because the client is offline.")){
     finish();
     startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

This code must be placed in `addOnFailureListener`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using Chrome Extension `Moesif CORS`. I disabled the extension and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using a leading slash in the database URL:

```
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(CREDENTIALS_PATH), 
    databaseURL: "https://databasename.firebaseio.com/"
                                      // remove this ^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem. but I've just fixed it. check your projectId is correct. when you use cloud firestore, you need it.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: 'XYZ',
    authDomain: 'XYZ.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://XYZ.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: 'XYZ.appspot.com',
    projectId: 'XYZ' // <--- make sure project ID is here 
  }
};
```

Comment: it is correct. Firestore works sometimes, but sometimes that errors throws

Answer (score 0):

For me, enabling `({ synchronizeTabs: true } )` seems to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone ever faces this issue on the web (server side code), simply try restarting the server and again `ping` the endpoint that connects to `firebase`. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this issue along with a warning that I should change my database location as it was in a different region. 
I added a databaseURL property in the firebaseconfig with the url of my dsatabase and it worked properly after that.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I previously tested my app with the `firebase-local-emulator` and therefore had some configurations for it still enabled, for example:

```
Firebase.firestore.apply {
    if (DomainConstants.isOnTest) useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 8080)
}
```

Because I forgot to set `isOnTest = false`, the app relied on the `firebase-local-emulators` data (which was not running) and threw `client is offline error`.

Long story short: Check if you configured your project using `firebase-local-emulator` and turn it off when you want to use your "real" database

Answer (score 0):

Saw this error in the console, Enabling Datastore might help.

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.9): Could not reach Cloud
> Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error:
> FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: The project my-project does not exist
> or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore
> database. Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to create a
> project or
> https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=my-project to
> add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud
> Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app
> and this app must not be disabled. This typically indicates that your
> device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The
> client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully
> connect to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the backend server by deploying a minor change fixed the issue for me

Answer (score -5):

Try to use VPN, It will work!.
Me i switched to VPN and it worked 100%. Sometimes Firebase fail to respond to IPs addresses of some countries.