# Failed to get document because the client is offline

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm using Flutter for a mobile app and have been noticing a intermittent bug recently that makes it so that reading documents from cloud firestore fails. I finally got one of my devices to get the bug so I plugged it in to get logs and I got this error when I tried accessing one of the documents.

> flutter : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing get, Failed to get document because the client is offline., null)

This error is thrown from this line of my code, which works for 99.9% of users 99.9% of the time

```
DocumentSnapshot userLivestream = await Firestore.instance.collection('livestreams').document(userId).get();
```

I've done a lot of reading up on the topic and got a lot of mixed answers. One stack overflow post said it was fixed like 2.5 years ago(obviously not, ref: [Firebase Cloud Firestore throws "client is offline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602889/firebase-cloud-firestore-throws-client-is-offline)), and others said it was android specific (ref: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/631), but I am experiencing the same issue on both android and iOS. This problem has gotten worse recently, so maybe it is something with the package I am using. The relevant packages here are pasted from my pubspec.yaml.

```
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.11.0+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1
```

sometimes the bug fixes itself after a while, it might have something to do with logging into the app or changing the network the device is connected to, but with that information I still can't consistently replicate the issue. Has anyone run into a similar issue and how did you fix it?

stack trace:

```
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing get, Failed to get document because the client is offline., null)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : <asynchronous suspension>
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:349)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #3      DocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:76)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #4      LivestreamRepository.getUsersLivestream (package:hallo/repositories/livestream_repository.dart:81)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #5      joinLivestream (package:hallo/presentation/widgets/livestream_previews.dart:448)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #6      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:45)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #7      joinLivestream (package:hallo/presentation/widgets/livestream_previews.dart:447)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #8      LiveStreamMenuState._buildLivestreamList.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:hallo/livestream/livestream_screen.dart:463)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:45)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #10     LiveStreamMenuState._buildLivestreamList.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:hallo/livestream/livestream_screen.dart:460)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #11     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #12     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #14     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #15     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273)
03-31 13:20:09.488 19623  6084 E flutter : #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182)
```

Comment: "One stack overflow post said it was fixed like 2.5 years ago(obviously not), and others said it was android specific," When including something like this, always include a link to the source please, so we can check what they said/meant.

Comment: thanks, I've added links to those issues.

Comment: The versions you use definitely look a bit older (>6 months), but I doubt that is the problem. I'm not sure why the clients would throw that error on the line of code you shared. Can you do two things: 1) share the complete stack trace for the error? 2) upgrade to the latest SDK versions? Hopefully with both we can either see what causes it on your end, or work towards getting a repro for a bug report.

Comment: I added stack trace, what do you mean most recent sdk?

Comment: You seems to be a bit behind, so upgrade to the latest versions as shown here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire#available-flutterfire-plugins (hmmm, some of the version numbers are not showing right now, so be sure to click through).

Comment: I'm up to date now. I'm trying to replicate the bug. Like I said above, most of the time everything works fine, so I'm trying to find a repro.

Comment: Wondering if you've found a solution? I've run into the same problem but haven't found a workaround. I've filed a bug report with flutterfire but they haven't been able to reproduce the issue (https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4305)... most likely because they're testing with ADB running, which I've found prevents the issue from occurring.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue. I tried to reference the collection which is not yet created. So, I just created a collection with dummy doc. And now it's working good.

> The cloud_firestore developers should have to take concern on error reports.