# Why are some of my users seeing "Failed to get document because the client is offline"?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

This has been an ongoing problem over the years that Google can't seem to solve. In my case, it happens occasionally. I now have 34 out of 2700 active users who've experienced this bug and setting persistance enabled to true had no effect (it's supposed to be true by default, but I thought I'd try). The only reported problem I've found which was intermittent is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961181/failed-to-get-document-because-the-client-is-offline). In my case, I'm downloading a document and catching it after checking if the operation had been successful:

```
        mUserDocRef.get().addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>) task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
               // Do something
                  .
                  .
            } else {
               // Do something else
                  .
                  .
                  .
            }
        } else {
            crashlytics.log("getSettings error" + task.getException().getMessage());
            return;
        }
    });
```

Does anyone know if Google is actively pursuing this bug? For my users, it's a big deal and needs to be resolved.

Comment: It is unclear about which problem you are talking.

Comment: If you have a bug report, you should file that with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I did and am waiting for them to reply.