# Nuxt3 & Firebase JS SDK V9 error - Failed to get document because the client is offline

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to connect to firestore from a Nuxt3 app. But on the server side rendering it throws this error:

```
error [FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.] {
  code: 'unavailable',
  customData: undefined,
  toString: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Any idea why this happens? How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can activate online persistence, by following the instructions https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#web-version-9 choose the version correctly. This seems to be an error with the SDK -> [Firebase Cloud Firestore throws "client is offline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602889/firebase-cloud-firestore-throws-client-is-offline)